# Laravel User - Role many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have created a Role table which has a many to many relationship with the User table. Models and everything in place plus i can seed all tables correct to create a default user + 3 roles.

I want to modify the scaffolded register controller so i can attach a role along with the other attributes (name, mail etc). The default create method looks something like this:

```
protected function create(array $data)

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

how do i call Role model ? and how do i pass it in the create function and ultimately to the view ?
My initial thought was:

```
use App\Role;
```

at the beginning of the file and

```
$roles = Role::all();
```

maybe on the create function ? that is probably wrong but i cannot think something else.

Plus how do i call it after on the view  ? Role table has 3 predefined roles as i mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create user first, then you need to attach roles and return user instance. This should work for you:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $roles = [2, 4];

    $user->roles()->attach($roles);

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but: that assumes the roles are of id 2 and 4 respectively (if i get it right), i want to have the register view give me dropdown list of the roles in the database and then attach the one that the admin will provide.

Dont mind the looks but how do i modify the register view to show the roles already in the DB and then attach them ?

Comment: Will it be wise to write my own register view and a second controller ? just for the ease maybe of it and not meddling with the registersUsers trait of laravel

Comment: 2 and 4 are just an example to show you the idea and format. Of course you need to change this for your needs. If recommend you to edit and use built in auth system including controller, views etc.